# Run NodeJS command on Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, command-line-interface

I am fairly new to NodeJS development. I have no issues whatsoever running commands on my local machine. For instance, say I want to install a package called "formidable" on my Node server, I'd run the command 'npm install formidable'. If I have deployed my NodeJS application to Azure, how would I run the same command?

NB - I do not want to manually run the command on my local machine and then deploy to Azure. This will take far too long, since I have to install many packages each with many files in them.

Please advise on how I go about doing this?

Thanks

Comment: are you deploying to azure webapp (azure sites)

Comment: Yes @Sgrm, I am. I went to the gallery and chose "NodeJS Empty Web App" under Azure Webapp.

Comment: well since you already got the answer all is well. anyway if it was correct you should mark it up as such

Comment: Well, there's Joe's solution and then there's Gary's. Both work, so I had asked a question yesterday about safety on Joe's answer. I was waiting for him to reply before I chose the safest one for my case. He had not replied by the time I went to sleep. Please see his answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running an Azure Web App you can use Kudu Services.

To do this

- browse to http://yoursitename.**scm**.azurewebsites.net
- It will ask you to authenticate if you have not already
- Click on Debug Console -> CMD

You can run your npm commands from there.

Screen shot below

[image]

More information can be found here: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki

Comment: That was relatively easy and painfree. Thanks for your time. I'm guessing KUDU is a Microsoft (or trusted by) tool that I can recommend to my boss. Is that so?

Comment: Yes, you can absolutely recommend it. Also, being this worked for you can you make sure to select my response as the answer? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Beside login KUDU console site and run command in online cmdlet. You also can configure dependencies in `package.json`, then you deploy your nodejs application to Azure via GIT, it will automatically install the dependencies in this file.

For example:

You add the `formidable` module in dependencies:

[image]

Then deploy it application on Azure Web Apps, you can see the remoting deployment logs in cmdlet that the module was added in the application on Azure, e.g.:
[image]

You can refer to [Create a Node.js web app in Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-nodejs-develop-deploy-mac/) for how to create  a nodejs application and deploy via GIT.

Comment: Thanks a million. I had already configured it to use Github and had a package.json from my local repository that had the package included. However, I didn't know it would actually install the packages in the package.json. Thanks for your time.