# run node.js servers in azure as post deployment action hook

Tags: azure, kudu

**Can I run a node.js server in azure as a post deployment action hook?**

Details shown below:

the command is : `npm run test:servers`

Tried adding a post deployment action in deploy.cmd(shown below), but it's just ignored after the deployment completes (no errors, and the deployment is successful).

```
:: Post deployment stub
IF DEFINED POST_DEPLOYMENT_ACTION call npm run test:servers
IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
```

Here's what my Jenkins console output looks like:

```
remote: checking if package.json exists[K
remote: Finished successfully.[K
remote: Running post deployment command(s)...[K
remote: Deployment successful.[K
Notifying upstream projects of job completion
```

if I use the debug console (like [so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33758298/run-nodejs-command-on-azure)), it looks like I'll have to run the command after each deployment which I'd much rather not do.

May be deploy.cmd is not configured properly?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use `postinstall` script in *package.json* to run the command?

For example, you can use the following to run `npm run test:servers` after the package is installed.

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "npm run test:servers"
}
```

Comment: that will run the servers, but deployment hangs (and FAILS eventually) because the servers just keep running - they are never meant to complete (unlike most other scripts that run to completion)

Answer (score 1):

Though `package.json` is how we do this nearly everywhere, Azure does NOT respect many of the `package.json` actions, so those weren't an option for me.

You are definitely on the right track. Having succeeded in this myself, here's what I did:

Here is the exact code from my `deploy.cmd` which I added just before `goto end`:

```
IF EXIST "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%\publish.js" (
  pushd "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%"
  node "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%\publish.js"
  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
  popd
)
```

Do whatever you want in `publish.js`. In my case, I do HTTP and Redis calls. In my tests, I set a key in Redis so I knew for a fact that it was called and not skipped. So, you can do anything. You just need to do what you need to do from there.

The only caveat: **for my scenario, it seems to hang for a bit sometimes, but it eventually continues**.